# Display non repeated items on multiple queries

Tags: php, mysql

My table structure looks like this,

1. ID - primary index, AI.
2. Title - Title of the product or any item.
3. Tags - This will have tags about the product or item. Seperated by commas. Example if the product is an Android Mobile, the tags may be Android, Mobile, [Brand], [Operating System].

Now I would like to display the products in groups. Like first I will display a box with category Mobile phones. And the next box with Android mobiles or any particluar brand mobiles.

And I query the database using this logic,

```
SELECT * FROM `database`.`tablename` WHERE `tag` LIKE '%Mobile%'
```

So that this will return the mobile phones in general.

Now again

```
SELECT * FROM `database`.`tablename` WHERE `tag` LIKE '%Samsung%'
```

This query is for sorting out by brand Samsung.

Now the problem definition is I need to omit the results which were previously displayed in the previous query. I mean the mobile models displayed in the first query must not be displayed when I query for brand Samsung. Since the queries are run seperately I don't know how can I do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM `database`.`tablename` WHERE `tag` LIKE '%Samsung%' AND `tag` NOT LIKE '%Mobile%'
```

Or you could try something like this:

```
 SELECT * FROM `database`.`tablename` GROUP BY tag
```

And sort the tags with PHP

Comment: I cannot use this because the number of groups displayed in a page will be in n numbers and each query will be made dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can have this result using MINUS.  Unfortunately we don't have it on Mysql, but you can use the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `tag`
FROM `database`.`tablename` a LEFT JOIN `database`.`tablename` b USING (`tag`)
WHERE `tag` IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
SELECT *
FROM `database`.`tablename`
WHERE `tag` LIKE '%Samsung%'
AND `ID` NOT IN (SELECT `ID`
                 FROM `database`.`tablename`
                 WHERE `tag` LIKE '%Mobile%')
```

or just

```
SELECT *
FROM `database`.`tablename`
WHERE `tag` LIKE '%Samsung%'
AND `tag` NOT LIKE '%Mobile%'
```

But please take a note that your data is not normalized (the `tag` column specifically). Take a look at [Third normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form) and [Boyce–Codd normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyce%E2%80%93Codd_normal_form).